# Non-blocking socket in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

Is it me, or can I not find a good tutorial on non-blocking sockets in python?

I'm not sure how to exactly work the `.recv` and the `.send` in it. According to the python docs, (my understanding of it, at least) the `recv`'ed or `send`'ed data might be only partial data. So does that mean I have to somehow concatenate the data while `recv` and make sure all data sends through in `send`. If so, how? An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/select/

Comment: You probably want to discriminate between send() and sendall(). http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/firefox-sync-python/ Also you probably want to use some high level asynchronous IO framework like Eventlet: http://eventlet.net/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if your socket is in non-blocking mode or not, recv/send work pretty much the same; the only difference is that non-blocking socket throws 'Resource temporarily unavailable' error instead of waiting for data/socket.

**recv** method returns numbers of bytes received, which is told to be less or equal to the passed bufsize. If you want to receive exactly *size* bytes, you should do something similar to the following code:

```
def recvall(sock, size):
  data = ''
  while len(data) < size:
    d = sock.recv(size - len(data))
    if not d:
      # Connection closed by remote host, do what best for you
      return None
    data += d
  return data
```

This is important to remember, that in blocking mode you have to do exactly the same. (The number of bytes passed to application layer is for example limited by recv buffer size in the OS.)

**send** method returns number of bytes sent, which is told to be less or equal to the length of passed string. If you want to ensure the whole message was sent, you should do something similar to the following code:

```
def sendall(sock, data):
  while data:
    sent = sock.send(data)
    data = data[sent:]
```

You can use sock.sendall directly, but (according to the documentation) *on error, an exception is raised, and there is no way to determine how much data, if any, was successfully sent*.

The sockets in Python follow the BSD socket API and behave in the similar way to c-style sockets (the difference is, for example, they throw exception instead of returning error code). You should be happy with any socket tutorial on the web and manpages.

Comment: Thanks for accepting @ultimatebuster, I just realised the error handling in `recvall` wasn't too good and added `if not d` to handle closed connections.

Comment: "Y ru doing It works the same!!!" Might as well not do anything because everything "works the same"

Answer (score 1):

Keep bytes you want to send in a buffer.  (A list of byte-strings would be best, since you don't have to concatenate them.)  Use the `fcntl.fcntl` function to set the socket in non-blocking mode:

```
import fcntl, os
fcntl.fcntl(mysocket, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

Then `select.select` will tell you when it is OK to read and write to the socket.  (Writing when it is not OK will give you the `EAGAIN` error in non-blocking mode.)  When you write, check the return value to see how many bytes were actually written.  Eliminate that many bytes from your buffer.  If you use the list-of-strings approach, you only need to try writing the first string each time.

If you read the empty string, your socket has closed.

Comment: There's also [`mysocket.setblocking(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking).