# Python Socket (Simple server script)

Tags: python, sockets

I have this **simple server script**. My objective for this script is :

1. Wait for a client connection
2. Receive massages from client until the client disconnect
3. Once client disconnect, wait for another client to connect
4. Receive massages until the client disconnect
5. Repeat...

---

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("",5000))
server_socket.listen(5)
print "Awaiting Client connection"
client_socket, address =server_socket.accept()
print "Connection established.. with ",address
while True:
    data=client_socket.recv(512)
    if not data:
        client_socket.close()
        print "Client disconnected, Awaiting new connections..."
        client_socket, address =server_socket.accept()
        print "Connection from ",address
    else:
        print "RECIEVED:",data
```

---

My Question is even though the script seems to be working when i test it on a pair of pc, i noticed that after it received the connection from the client, that is  `line no 7`

```
print "Connection established.. with ",address
```

the python shell window seems unresponsive (become not responding if i try to move the shell window) until the client send any message.

As far as i understand, if there is no incoming message from client, `client_socket.recv(512)` will just wait for the data from the client.

But why it became unresponsive?
To make things clearer,

-the script works just fine ( it receive data and print it out from screen & wait for the new connection if client disconnect)

-the cursor in console windows stop blinking

-when i try to move the console window around , it become unresponsive and windows give me a message "this program has stopped responding"

Comment: The `recv` method is blocking - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770567/python-tcp-socket-blocks-on-recv-method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you script blocks on the `accept` call that is present after this line :

```
print "Client disconnected, Awaiting new connections..."
```

The `accept` call will return only when a particular client has attempted to connect to server. That is when your script will continue execution to the next line. This is the reason why you would see a message like **This program is not responding** in Windows.

You could consider the use of non-blocking socket I/O approach in order to ensure that your script is responsive.

Refer to [this](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html) link for description of blocking and non-blocking calls. Also you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715944/non-blocking-socket-in-python) question to understand how to implement Non-blocking sockets in Python - and of course there are plenty of web resources too.

Hope this helps