# Python Socket Download/Upload Image Files Missing Binaries

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I'm using python SocketServer to download/upload multi image files.

Server Code

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):

        '''
        Here is other codes......
        '''

        #start sending files to client...
        for img_name, img_size in dict_image_sizes.iteritems():
            image_file = open(u"%s\\%s" % (image_folder, img_name), 'rb')

            while True:
                image_chunk = image_file.read(32768)

                if not image_chunk:
                    break

                self.request.sendall(image_chunk)

            image_file.close()
```

Client Code:

```
    #start recving...
    for img_name, img_size in dict_image_sizes.iteritems():
        each_image_file = open(u'%s\\%s\\%s' % (env.cache_path, relative_path, img_name), 'wb')

        chunk_size = 4096

        img_size_int = int(int(img_size)/chunk_size)
        img_size_mod = int(math.fmod(int(img_size), chunk_size))

        import time
        image_chunk = ''
        for i in range(img_size_int):
            image_chunk += sock.recv(chunk_size)
            #time.sleep(0.001)

        image_chunk += sock.recv(img_size_mod)
        each_image_file.write(image_chunk)

        each_image_file.close()
```

The question is, if I unmark

```
            #time.sleep(0.001)
```

in Client Code, it will okay. If not, many images may get corrupted(not always, sometimes).

```
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
```

Is there any way to solve this problem? I tried to add

```
sock.settimeout(1)
```

for client, but its not work.

**Problem Solved. We need to check send/recv the exact bytes returned each time.
Consult Here: [Non-blocking socket in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715944/non-blocking-socket-in-python)**

```
def recvall(sock, size):
  data = ''
  while len(data) < size:
    d = sock.recv(size - len(data))
    if not d:
      # Connection closed by remote host, do what best for you
      return None
    data += d
  return data

def sendall(sock, data):
  while data:
    sent = sock.send(data)
    data = data[sent:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a max OS send/receive buffer size for socket connections. Without `time.sleep`, all the requests are send instantally the and fill the buffer.

Comment: Thanks! So, I think add re-send and re-recv check could solve the problem.